Media Foundation h.264 decoder artifact
I am developing a Windows 10 stream client which receives h.264 NALU packets frame by frame and decode them. The decoded frame are then consumed D3D11 video processor and converted into RGBA format D3D11 texture.
Currently, the media foundation H.264 decoder does its job and decodes the frames. However, the image quality deterioates in between key frames, especially for objects that are moving. All artifacts disappears when a new key frame is receieved which is expected. Here is a screenshot of the atrifact.
Here is how I set up my decoder:
IMFTransform* pDecoder;
IMFMediaType* pInputType;
IMFMediaType* pOutputType;

// HR checks are omitted to avoid visual clutter in this example. There are proper HR checks in place. 
void init(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t framerate) {
  MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMSH264DecoderMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDecoder);
  
  // Create Input Type
  MFCreateMediaType(&pInputType);
  pInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
  pInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
  MFSetAttributeRatio(pInputType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
  MFSetAttributeRatio(pInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, framerate, 1);
  MFSetAttributeSize(pInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height);
  pInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_MixedInterlaceOrProgressive);
  

  // Create Output Type
  MFCreateMediaType(&pOutputType); 
  pOutputputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
  pOutputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12);
  MFSetAttributeRatio(pInputType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
  MFSetAttributeRatio(pInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, framerate, 1);
  MFSetAttributeSize(pInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height);
  
  // Configure Decoder
  pDecoder->SetInputType(0, pInputType, 0);
  pDecoder->SetOutputType(0, pOutputType, 0);
  IMFAttributes* pAttributes;
  pDecoder->GetAttributes(&pAttributes);
  pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_LOW_LATENCY, TRUE);
  
  // Clean Up.
  ...
}

Things I have either confirmed or tried:

I have confirmed that the NALU packets are correct. I dumped the packets into a video file and no artifacts were present.
The network stack uses TCP so packets should arrive in order + there shouldn't be bit error.
No dropped frame were reported from the server side.
I have tried increasing and decreasing the bitrates. The only thing it affects is the quality of the stream but nothing for the artifacts.
I am aware of a similar question on stackoverflow. However, that solution offered in that question did not resolve my question. Setting the MF_LOW_LATENCY (i.e CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode) has no visible effect on the decoded frames.

My question is, what should I do to resolve this artifact?
Edit 1:
The server runs on MacOS and encodes frames with VideoToolbox.
The encoder fetches one frame at a time from a metal texture and converts it into a CVPixelBuffer. The pts is generated using a fixed increment: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(frameInedx * 0.017f)
Encoder Setup:
VTCompressionSessionRef encoder;
// Error checks are omitted for the same reason above. 
void initEncoder(ImageFormat format, int32_t width, int32_t height) {
  uint32_t bitrate = 8000000; // 8000kb
  uint32_t framerate = 60; 
  
  // Creation
  CFMutableDictionaryRef encoderSpec = 
  CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, NULL);
  CFDictionarySetValue(encoderSpec, 
  kVTVideoEncoderSpecification_EnableHardwareAcceleratedVideoEncoder, 
  kCFBooleanTrue);

  CFMutableDictionaryRef pxBufferAttributes = (__bridge 
  CFMutableDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
  [NSNumber numberWithInteger:format], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, 
  nil];
  VTCompressionSessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, 
  kCMVideoCodecType_H264, encoderSpec, pxBufferAttributes, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
  encoder);
  
  // Config
  VTSessionSetProperty(encoder, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime, 
  kCFBooleanTrue);
  VTSessionSetProperty(encoder, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel, 
  kVTProfileLevel_H264_High_5_1);
  VTSessionSetProperty(encoder, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate, 
  (__bridge CFTypeRef) @(bitrate));
  VTSessionSetProperty(encoder, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval, 
  (__bridge CFTypeRef) @(framerate * 2));
  VTSessionSetProperty(encoder, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate, 
  (__bridge CFTypeRef) @(framerate));
  VTCompressionSessionPrepareToEncodeFrames(encoder); 

  // Cleanup 
  ...                                        
}

Things I have tried with the encoder:

Adjusting the profile level.
Setting kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering to false to disable B-frames.
Setting kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowTemporalCompression to false to require key-frame-only compression.

None of the above fixes the issue.
I have tested the encoder output on mac using AVAssetWriter. AVAssetWriter was able to produce a video with zero artifacts.

It should still be a broken stream. Something wrong in edecoder input results in artifacted output.

can you show your encoder configuration? you may have B frames which your decoder isn't handling.

I was in the same situation, setting the options below cured the artifacts.
CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode            = 1
CODECAPI_AVDecVideoAcceleration_H264 = 1
CODECAPI_AVDecVideoMaxCodedWidth     = 4096
CODECAPI_AVDecVideoMaxCodedHeight    = 2304
Hope this helps.
